# Prove the given equality

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Prove that $\frac{a_1}{1+a_1} + \frac{a_2}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)} +\frac{a_3}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)(1+a_3)} ...\frac{a_n}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)..(1+a_n)}=1-\frac{1}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)..(1+a_n)}$

I am not able to figure out what sort of series is being formed, so I can I just get a hint to get me started?

Comment: What about induction?

Answer (score 1):

Induction step will give you:
$$\frac{a_1}{1+a_1} + \dots + \frac{a_n}{(1+a_1) \dots(1 + a_n)}  + \frac{a_{n+1}}{(1+a_1)\dots(1+a_{n+1})} = 1 - \frac{1}{(1+a_1)\dots(1+a_n)} + \frac{a_{n+1}}{(1+a_1) \dots(1+a_n)(1+a_{n+1})} = 1 - \frac{a_{n+1}}{(1+a_1) \dots(1+a_{n+1})}$$

Comment: Well, I had modified the question a bit. It was given in an MCQ format, so induction couldn’t have been used easily

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$\frac{a_1}{1+a_1} + \frac{a_2}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)}=1-\frac{1}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)}$